# Can WebSphere server acting as an SSL client provide its certificate list during handshake?

Tags: ssl, client, websphere, handshake

I am aware that in WebSphere Security, under SSL configurations -> QOS settings - I can make Client authentication as "Required". This would mean that during the SSL handshake, the client is supposed to authenticate itself by showing a certificate chain list to the server. The handshake would then proceed if the server also trusts one of the certs.

I am having a situation which is quite opposite to this.

My Websphere server acts as a client (sending a SOAP request to another server). But the other server also has client authentication set to true. While trying to debug the handshake, I found that my Websphere server isn't providing the cert list after te step ServerHello Done.

Is there any configuration in Websphere I can use to do this?

Here's the jist of the handshake:

```
Server A                    WebSphere serer(client)

                            *** ClientHello, TLSv1

*** ServerHello, TLSv1
*** Certificate chain
*** CertificateRequest
*** ServerHelloDone
[write back to client]

                            *** Certificate chain
                            [empty]


[At server A] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882730/1747983